# Gather filename information into XML node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have several XML files, as follows:

file : **1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val1</info1>
           <info2>val2</info2>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val3</info1>
           <info2>val4</info2>
       </info>
   </config>
```

file : **2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val5</info1>
           <info2>val6</info2>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val7</info1>
           <info2>val8</info2>
       </info>
   </config>
```

file: **3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val9</info1>
           <info2>val10</info2>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val11</info1>
           <info2>val12</info2>
       </info>
   </config>
```

using XSLT2.0 (saxon), I would like to merge them and also add to each  node:

```
<info3>XXX</info3>
```

and also

```
<file>filename.xml</file>
```

filename.xml was the file from which the info has been copied.

The output should look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <config>
       <info>
           <info1>val1</info1>
           <info2>val2</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
           <file>1.xml</file>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val3</info1>
           <info2>val4</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
           <file>1.xml</file>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val5</info1>
           <info2>val6</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
           <file>2.xml</file>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val7</info1>
           <info2>val8</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
           <file>2.xml</file>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val9</info1>
           <info2>val10</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
           <file>3.xml</file>
       </info>
       <info>
           <info1>val11</info1>
           <info2>val12</info2>
           <info3>XXX</info3>
           <file>3.xml</file>
       </info>
   </config>
```

So far I have been able to merge the file by creating an XML file that lists the file I want to merge (merge.xml):

```
<mergeData newRoot="config">
   <filelist>
       <fileItem>1.xml</fileItem>
       <fileItem>2.xml</fileItem>
       <fileItem>3.xml</fileItem>
   </filelist>
</mergeData>
```

using the following XSL (merge.xsl):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:param  name="new">
   <info>XXX</info>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:element name="{mergeData/@newRoot}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="mergeData/fileList/fileItem"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fileItem">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document(translate(., '\', '/'))/config/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config/*">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="$new"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   <file><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/></file>
 </xsl:template>
```

How should I modify the XSL to get the filename into each info at the same time.

Comment: Would you be willing to change your XSLT from a "template match" oriented structure to a more "template name" oriented structure? Then I think this should easily be solvable and I could offer my help.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT yields your required result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:param  name="new">
    <info>XXX</info>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/mergeData">
    <config>

    <xsl:for-each select="filelist/fileItem">
      <xsl:variable name="filename" select="text()"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="document($filename)/config/info">
        <info>
          <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
          <xsl:element name="info{count(*)+1}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$new"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <file><xsl:value-of select="$filename"/></file>
        </info>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </config>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- This already works with XSLT 1.0, hence I changed the XSLT declaration.
- Since this approach is *top down* with a predefined sub structure it does not use the attribute `newRoot` of your input file anymore.
- The answer does not extract the basename of your input files but uses the full path supplied in the merge configuration. You may want to revert this simplification. Of course, using `tokenize` pushes it back to XSLT 2.0 or extended functions.

Answer (score 0):

Really the only thing you should have to do is move `file` inside of the `xsl:copy`.

Example (with a couple of other minor mods):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param  name="new">
        <info3>XXX</info3>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{mergeData/@newRoot}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="mergeData/filelist/fileItem"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fileItem">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(translate(., '\', '/'))/config/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="config/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node(),$new"/>
            <file><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(/), '/')[last()]"/></file>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also do this using `collection()` instead of creating the separate `mergeData.xml` file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="newRoot" select="'config'"/>
    <xsl:param name="new">
        <info3>XXX</info3>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="{$newRoot}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('file:///C:/some/path?select=[0-9]*.xml')/*/info"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="info">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node(),$new"/>
            <file><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(/),'/')[last()]"/></file>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

One additional alternative, since you're using Saxon, is to use `saxon:discard-document()` along with your `mergeData.xml` input. If you have a lot of files listed in `mergeData.xml`, this can help with memory consumption. (It does require Saxon PE or EE or an older version of Saxon that allows the extension functions.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="new">
    <info3>XXX</info3>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/mergeData">
    <xsl:element name="{@newRoot}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="filelist/fileItem"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fileItem">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(.)/saxon:discard-document(.)/*/*" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>          
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="info">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node(),$new"/>
      <file><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(/),'/')[last()]"/></file>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```